# moment date difference is not working

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to do date difference using moment but it is showing incorrect days figure

```js
var before = moment('25-Sep-2017 13:44','DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm');
var now = moment('25-Sep-2017 13:46','DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm');

console.log(
  moment(now - before)
  .format('D[ day(s)] H[ hour(s)] m[ minute(s)] s[ second(s) ago.]')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `moment(now).diff(before, 'minutes')` will give 2, so no error with that one, it might be a timezone issue in the browser I will investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Use moment [`diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) to calculate the difference between two moment objects, instead of `-`, so you will have `now.diff(before)` instead of `moment(now - before)`.

Then you can use [`moment.duration(Number);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/) to create a [duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/):

> Moment.js also has duration objects. Where a moment is defined as single points in time, durations are defined as a length of time.

You can use [moment-duration-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) plug-in to get the duration value in the form of: *`'D[ day(s)] H[ hour(s)] m[ minute(s)] s[ second(s) ago.]'`*. See [`format`](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#template) method docs for more info.

Note that using moment-duration-format:

> Leading tokens are automatically trimmed when they have no value.

you can use [`{ trim: false }`](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#trim) option *to stop that behavior*.

Here a live sample:

```js
var before = moment('25-Sep-2017 13:44','DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm');
var now = moment('25-Sep-2017 13:46','DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm');

console.log(
  moment.duration( now.diff(before) )
  .format('D[ day(s)] H[ hour(s)] m[ minute(s)] s[ second(s) ago.]')
);

// With trim: false
console.log(
  moment.duration( now.diff(before) )
  .format('D[ day(s)] H[ hour(s)] m[ minute(s)] s[ second(s) ago.]', { trim: false })
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```